how to use the APISIX to limit the upload file size
I am using the Apache APISIX v3.8.0 as the gateway, now I need to upload some file to url /file/upload/abcd.png. how to limit the file size when upload? I have read the official document and did not found the clue.

There are many methods to limit the size of requests in APISIX:

using a built-in plugin, such as client-control;
using APISIX configuration;
making a custom plugin;

Since you want to enable it on a specific route (/file/upload/abcd.png), the best approach would be to use a plugin.
NB: I'll provide examples using httpbin.org website and Admin APIs. I'll assume we have APISIX running and accessible at localhost:9080 and the Admin API are exposed and accessible without key authentication, at localhost:9180. I'll also assume that we have 2 images in the current path:

abcd_small.png, with lower size than 1 MB;
abcd_large.png, with higher size than 1 MB;

Solutions
1. Built-in Plugins: client-control
client-control plugin can be used to limit the size of the body in client requests. From APISIX docs:

The client-control Plugin can be used to dynamically control the behavior of NGINX to handle a client request, by setting the max size of the request body.

You can enable it on the route which exposes endpoint /file/upload/abcd.png and set max_body_size attribute to your preferences.
Example (Admin API)
The following Admin API call enables the plugin client-control on any route starting with /file/upload/ and limits the request body size to 1MB (1048576 Bytes). The proxy rewrite redirects the request to httpbin.org/post endpoint, which is used to send a POST request.
curl -s -X PUT -i "http://localhost:9180/apisix/admin/routes/client-control1" -d '
{
    "uri": "/file/upload/*",
    "plugins": {
        "client-control": {
            "max_body_size": 1048576
        },
        "proxy-rewrite": {
            "method": "POST",
            "uri": "/post"
        }
    },
    "upstream": {
        "type": "roundrobin",
        "nodes": {
            "httpbin.org": 1
        }
    }
}'

We can test it with curl, by sending a request with a small image (< 1 MB) and with a large image (> 1 MB):
curl -s -i "localhost:9080/file/upload/abcd.png" -F "image=@./abcd_small.png" | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large

curl -s -i "localhost:9080/file/upload/abcd.png" -F "image=@./abcd_large.png" | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

2. Using APISIX Configuration
You can set nginx_config.http.client_max_body_size in APISIX configuration file (check config.yaml.example for reference), to limit the maximum body size of client requests.
Example
Create a file config.yaml with the following content:
nginx_config:
  http:
    client_max_body_size: 1048576

And mount it at ${apisix_root}/conf/config.yaml. Then start APISIX or hot reload:
apisix reload

Then create a simple example route:
curl -s -X PUT -i "http://localhost:9180/apisix/admin/routes/apisix-config1" -d '
{
    "uri": "/file/upload2/*",
    "plugins": {
        "proxy-rewrite": {
            "method": "POST",
            "uri": "/post"
        }
    },
    "upstream": {
        "type": "roundrobin",
        "nodes": {
            "httpbin.org": 1
        }
    }
}'

We can test it with curl:
curl -s -i "localhost:9080/file/upload2/abcd.png" -F "image=@./abcd_small.png" | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large

curl -s -i "localhost:9080/file/upload2/abcd.png" -F "image=@./abcd_large.png" | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

3. Using Custom Plugin
You can make a custom Lua plugin (or an external plugin) and exploit, for example, the Content Lenght header.
Example
Content of custom Lua plugin limit-upload-size.lua:
local core = require("apisix.core")
local ngx = ngx

local schema = {
    type = "object",
    properties = {
        max_size = {type = "integer", minimum = 1},
    },
    required = {"max_size"},
}

local _M = {
    version = 0.1,
    priority = 10,
    name = "limit-upload-size",
    schema = schema,
}

function _M.check_schema(conf)
    return core.schema.check(schema, conf)
end

function _M.access(conf, ctx)
    local max_size = conf.max_size
    local content_length = tonumber(ngx.req.get_headers()["content-length"])
    
    if content_length and content_length > max_size then
        return 413, { message = "Content cannot exceed " .. conf.max_size .. " Bytes" }
    end
end

return _M

We need to enable it by editing the APISIX configuration by appending the plugin name to the plugins list, under plugins field; or by adding the plugin path to apisix.extra_lua_path. Then we can enable it on a route like we did in other examples:
curl -s -X PUT -i "http://localhost:9180/apisix/admin/routes/limit-update-size1" -d '
{
    "uri": "/file/upload3/*",
    "plugins": {
        "limit-update-size": {
            "max_body_size": 1048576
        },
        "proxy-rewrite": {
            "method": "POST",
            "uri": "/post"
        }
    },
    "upstream": {
        "type": "roundrobin",
        "nodes": {
            "httpbin.org": 1
        }
    }
}'

We can test it with curl:
curl -s -i "localhost:9080/file/upload3/abcd.png" -F "image=@./abcd_small.png" | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large

curl -s -i "localhost:9080/file/upload3/abcd.png" -F "image=@./abcd_large.png" | grep HTTP
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

